# Current store is 1 when running upgrade scripts

Tags: store-view, install-script

Any idea why `Mage::app()->getStore()` returns the store view with id 1 when inside the upgrade scripts independent on the store view I'm running the upgrade script in (even admin)?
I mean, I know where the code that does this is. In `Mage_Core_Model_App::getStore()` there is this:

```
    if (!Mage::isInstalled() || $this->getUpdateMode()) {
        return $this->_getDefaultStore();
    }
```

and `_getDefaultStore` looks like this:

```
   if (empty($this->_store)) {
        $this->_store = Mage::getModel('core/store')
            ->setId(self::DISTRO_STORE_ID)
            ->setCode(self::DISTRO_STORE_CODE);
    }
    return $this->_store;
```

`$this->_store` is always empty when reaching the method above.

I get the same result even if I add this at the top of the upgrade script:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
```

I'm curious about the business logic of having this 'feature'.

Comment: I thought upgrade scripts are always running in frontend scope. Often I tell the upgrade scripts explicit to use the admin store for the following lines.

Comment: @bukart. I tried explicitly telling the upgrade script to run the admin store view, but I get the same result. See my last 3 lines in the question.

Comment: I tried to answer your question below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NB: don't forget that the admin store scope isn't set until dispatching is taking place and a controller extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` executes (see the `adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start` event and related observer in `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::preDispatch()`).**

> I'm curious about the business logic of having this 'feature'.

You aren't the only one; that said, we may never know unless [Moshe](https://twitter.com/unirgy) or [Dima](https://twitter.com/dmitriysoroka) wants to discuss.

Setup scripts execute early in application initialization. The design of this is probably due so that, by the time the rest of the stack is executed, the necessary migrations and other work would be "done" - meaning that the system was ready to use right away even when a module was being installed or upgraded. I'm wondering if the original architects initially ever thought there would be a need for a more initialized system.  **I'll conjecture that, whereas much of the code *assumes* that there is a store instance available, the `_getDefaultStore()` logic ensures that there is a store instance.**

Full scope settings are available in 1.4.0.0 and up via data setup scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, to use the admin store in your upgrade scripts just use

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Your approach `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));` <strike>can't succeed, cause there's no really existing loadable storeview for admin</strike>

Often I use a pattern like this:

```
// remembering old current store
$currentStore = Mage::app()->getCurrentStore();

// switching to admin store
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// switching back to old current store
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($currentStore->getStoreId());
```

Otherwise sometimes after an upgrade script was executed your visitors will be redirected to the admin page instead of the frontend sometimes.

---

**Update:**

I misinterpreted the question below, so here's a new try to explain ^^

The upgrade scripts are called from a method deeper in the core (`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::_modifyResourceDb(...)`)

Here I tried to list the stack

- `Mage_Core_Model_App::run($params)`
- `Mage_Core_Model_App::_initModules()`
- `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()`
- `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyUpdates()`
- `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::_upgradeResourceDb($oldVersion, $newVersion)`
- `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::_modifyResourceDb($actionType, $fromVersion, $toVersion)`

**and now have a look at `Mage_Core_model_App::run($params)`:**

```
public function run($params)
{
    $options = isset($params['options']) ? $params['options'] : array();
    $this->baseInit($options);
    Mage::register('application_params', $params);

    if ($this->_cache->processRequest()) {
        $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    } else {
        $this->_initModules();
        $this->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);

        if ($this->_config->isLocalConfigLoaded()) {
            $scopeCode = isset($params['scope_code']) ? $params['scope_code'] : '';
            $scopeType = isset($params['scope_type']) ? $params['scope_type'] : 'store';
            $this->_initCurrentStore($scopeCode, $scopeType);
            $this->_initRequest();
            Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();
        }

        $this->getFrontController()->dispatch();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

the method `_initModules()` is called before the `$scopeCode` and `$scopeType` is determined.

*Currently I cannot figure out where the assumed fallback is defined.*

Comment: Oh, but there is a loadable store view for admin. take a look in the `core_store` table. There is a record with id `0`. Also if you try this `var_dump(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID))` you will get a valid instance of the admin store. Also tried `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);` but I get the same result. But my question wasn't about how to set the admin store in upgrade scripts. I was asking why `Mage::app()->getStore()` returns the store with id 1 in upgrade scripts.

Comment: oh... right... there's an admin store in database, indeed.

Comment: Hmm...I knew the stack but now that I've seen it in your answer it hit me. The updates should run somehow 'stateless'. But in order to run something you need a store. Hence a default value for the store. Now the only thing that does not make sense is: Why is this default store not `0` (admin) and is a store view that could easily get deleted from the admin UI? +1 for opening my eyes. If I don't get an other clear answer on this I will accept this.

Comment: mhh... good question... maybe after lunch I'll take a look ... interresting ^^

Comment: As of 1.9.3.6, `Mage::app()->getCurrentStore();` does not appear to be  defined and gives a fatal error when called. Instead, I got the ID using `$currentStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();`.

Answer (score 2):

So the basic answer is that it actually gets into the 3rd if.....wait what :(

```
if (!isset($id) || ''===$id || $id === true) {
    $id = $this->_currentStore;
}
```

For me it returns true for `Mage::isInstalled()` and false for `$this->getUpdateMode()` which sounds wrong. But this only happens on the first hit of `getStore`.

So it appears that it sets up the store before the update mode has been set, then when it comes back in the set-up script it uses the default store call which using the following code:

```
$this->_store = Mage::getModel('core/store')
    ->setId(self::DISTRO_STORE_ID)
    ->setCode(self::DISTRO_STORE_CODE);
```

The value of `self::DISTRO_STORE_ID` is 1 I guess cause it needs something and was not setup to us the admin store :(

So I actually have a system that has not store with id 1 and update script appear to be working well. If we are adding tables/attributes it is fine and even when adding site specific cms block this is also working, but we do get all store id and specifically set them when saving store specific data.

Comment: I dug up the same thing. What I don't understand is "Magento why u no use admin store for upgrades?". It seams more reasonable. I'm afraid to think what happens if I delete the store with id 1.

Comment: No one would be crazy enough to delete the default store ;)

Comment: Now that I know this, I won't be crazy, but the fact that it's possible...well...never trust a user.

Comment: One of our PM asked me if he could remove old stores last week. I think I replied with "What's the worst that could happen"....and even more odd in our current project setup we have no store with id 1 :( in the table `core_store` but setup scripts are working

Comment: But we specifically set store ids when we need store specific data saved

Comment: Hmmm...You might be on to something. Maybe this is just a placeholder. Some dummy store instance that is needed in order for Magento to function properly until the current store is initialized. Now I'm curious. When I will get the time I will delete the default store to check this. I think you should add your comment to the answer. It seams like valuable information.

Comment: adding a cms block should be done in a data upgrade (not install) script where the store scope is not locked to the Mage_Core_Model_App::DISTRO_STORE_CODE;

more in general, install scripts are used to change data structure (and have store scope locked) while data upgrade are used to change data content (and store scope can be changed during the script)