# How to mass update product attribute value using install script?

Tags: product-attribute

If we comment  **Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);** then its work fine, but product update not reflected.

```
 $installer = $this;
        try{
            $productTypes = array(
                Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE,
                Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE
             );
            $productTypes = join(',', $productTypes);

            $installer->startSetup();
        $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'discount', array(
            'group'             => 'Prices',
            'type'              => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
            'backend'           => '',
            'frontend'          => '',
            'label'             => 'Discount',
            'input'             => 'price',
            'class'             => '',
            'source'            => '',
            'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible'           => true,
            'required'          => false,
            'user_defined'      => true,
            'default'           => '',
            'searchable'        => false,
            'filterable'        => true,
            'comparable'        => false,
            //'visible_on_front'  => true,
            'unique'            => false,
            'apply_to'          => $productTypes,
            'is_configurable'   => false
        ));

      Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
      $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

     foreach($products as $_product) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());

          if($product->getFinalPrice() < $product->getPrice()){

            $diffAmt = $product->getPrice() - $product->getFinalPrice();
            $discountPer = ($diffAmt/ $product->getPrice()) * 100;
            $product->setDiscount($discountPer);
            $product->save();
          }
     }

        $installer->endSetup();
        }
        catch(Exception $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($array_product, array('attribute_code' => "something pretty"), 0);`

`$array_product` => array of product ids, which could be easily fetched

using `Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->getAllIds()`

`attribute_code` => is your attribute code

`something pretty` => your attribute value

`0` is `store id` replace with your `store id`

Comment: Thank you Keyur, Can you please read my comments at Marius answer ? I am facing that one issue.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you set the admin store in an install script has not effect. Read this for a clearer explanation: [Current store is 1 when running upgrade scripts](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/30482/146)

But you can still use `updateAttributes`
Something like this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->addTaxPercents();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if($product->getFinalPrice() < $product->getPrice()){
        $diffAmt = $product->getPrice() - $product->getFinalPrice();
        $discountPer = ($diffAmt/ $product->getPrice()) * 100;
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
             array($product->getId()), //products to update
             array('discount' => $discountPer), //attributes to update
             0 //store to update. 0 means global values
        );
    }
}
```

This way you avoid calling `load` in loops that is a real performance killer.

Comment: Hi Marius, Above code is useful to achieve what I want. This script is working fine If I execute it from external file. But still not working from mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php. I traced the code with all conditions too. It seems fine but update value of attribute is not working.

Comment: Strange. I used this and it worked.  You can try to split your install script in 2. One that adds the attribute and one that does the update.

Comment: Marius, I have split code into 2 file. `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` for create an attributes and `mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php` for update value to that attribute. But not updating value when you install it.